# How to Enable/Disable a button based on all editetext is not empty using viewmodel and databinding in kotlin android

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, data-binding

I need to create a `Login Activity` in an Android app using Data Binding with `ViewModel` using **Kotlin**. I want to enable/disable a Button based on the content of an `EditText` field. The expected behavior that I'm trying to achieve is the button should get enabled only when none of the`EditText` fields is empty.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**: In `ViewModel` declare

`var isEnabled : ObservableBoolean? = null` and initialize it in `init` block.

**Step 2**: Set value of `isEnabled` in your Text Change Listener like

`isEnabled?.set(!isLoginFormValid())`

**Step 3**: bind variable in `xml` file like

`android:enabled="@{viewmodel.isEnabled}"`

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean MediatorLiveData in your ViewModel and bind this to the enabled attribute of the button.

You should have MutableLiveData fields that's two-way bound to your EditTexts.  Add these as MutableLiveData as sources to the boolean MediatorLiveData so that it can observe changes to the EditTexts as user enters values.

Add whatever logic in the MediatorLiveData observers to set it's value to true/false depending on whatever logic you want (e.g. values of the EditTexts should not be null or empty)

Answer (score 0):

you can put validations in the on click method of the login button.like:-

if(edittext_one!=null){then do the code here for the onclick }

like this you can put as much validations as you want on the edittext using if else statements.i hope this helps